# I need to hide the upper part TRX_STATUS and TRX_COUNT in the RESULT

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select
trx_status,
sum(trx_count)
from (
    select
    case
        when status = 'GR001' then 'GR001'
        when status = 'GR002' then 'GR002'
        when status = 'GR003' then 'GR003'
        when status = 'GR018' then 'GR018'
        when status = 'GR033' then 'GR033'
        when status = 'GR043' then 'GR043'
        when status = 'GR052' then 'GR052'
        when status = 'GR152' then 'GR152'
        when status = 'FR030' then 'FR030'
        when status = 'RM033' then 'RM033'
        when status = 'RM041' then 'RM041'
        when status = 'FR017' then 'FR017'
        when status = 'GR013' then 'GR013'
        when status = 'GR092' then 'GR092'
        when status = 'GR049' then 'GR049'
        when status = 'GR124' then 'GR124'
        when status = 'GR069' then 'GR069'
        when status = 'FR013' then 'FR013'
        when status = 'GR036' then 'GR036'
        when status = 'GR055' then 'GR055'
        when status not in ('GR001', 'GR002', 'GR003', 'GR018', 'GR033', 'GR043', 'GR052', 'GR152', 'FR030', 'RM033',  'RM041', 'FR017', 'GR013', 'GR092',  'GR049', 'GR124', 'GR069', 'FR013', 'GR036', 'GR055') then 'OTHERS'
    end as trx_status,
    count(status) as trx_count
    from receive_otp
    where created_at between '2021-10-09 00:00:00' and '2021-10-09 23:59:00'
    group by trx_status
    union
    select
    case
        when status = 'GR001' then 'GR001'
        when status = 'GR002' then 'GR002'
        when status = 'GR003' then 'GR003'
        when status = 'GR018' then 'GR018'
        when status = 'GR033' then 'GR033'
        when status = 'GR043' then 'GR043'
        when status = 'GR052' then 'GR052'
        when status = 'GR152' then 'GR152'
        when status = 'FR030' then 'FR030'
        when status = 'RM033' then 'RM033'
        when status = 'RM041' then 'RM041'
        when status = 'FR017' then 'FR017'
        when status = 'GR013' then 'GR013'
        when status = 'GR092' then 'GR092'
        when status = 'GR049' then 'GR049'
        when status = 'GR124' then 'GR124'
        when status = 'GR069' then 'GR069'
        when status = 'FR013' then 'FR013'
        when status = 'GR036' then 'GR036'
        when status = 'GR055' then 'GR055'
        when status not in ('GR001', 'GR002', 'GR003', 'GR018', 'GR033', 'GR043', 'GR052', 'GR152', 'FR030', 'RM033',  'RM041', 'FR017', 'GR013', 'GR092',  'GR049', 'GR124', 'GR069', 'FR013', 'GR036', 'GR055') then 'OTHERS'
   end as trx_status,
    count(status) as trx_count
    from receive_obt
    where created_at between '2021-10-09 00:00:00' and '2021-10-09 23:59:00'
    group by trx_status
    union
    select
    case
           when status = 'GR001' then 'GR001'
        when status = 'GR002' then 'GR002'
        when status = 'GR003' then 'GR003'
        when status = 'GR018' then 'GR018'
        when status = 'GR033' then 'GR033'
        when status = 'GR043' then 'GR043'
        when status = 'GR052' then 'GR052'
        when status = 'GR152' then 'GR152'
        when status = 'FR030' then 'FR030'
        when status = 'RM033' then 'RM033'
        when status = 'RM041' then 'RM041'
        when status = 'FR017' then 'FR017'
        when status = 'GR013' then 'GR013'
        when status = 'GR092' then 'GR092'
        when status = 'GR049' then 'GR049'
        when status = 'GR124' then 'GR124'
        when status = 'GR069' then 'GR069'
        when status = 'FR013' then 'FR013'
        when status = 'GR036' then 'GR036'
        when status = 'GR055' then 'GR055'
        when status not in ('GR001', 'GR002', 'GR003', 'GR018', 'GR033', 'GR043', 'GR052', 'GR152', 'FR030', 'RM033',  'RM041', 'FR017', 'GR013', 'GR092',  'GR049', 'GR124', 'GR069', 'FR013', 'GR036', 'GR055') then 'OTHERS'
    end as trx_status,
    count(status) as trx_count
    from receive_wlt
    where created_at between '2021-10-09 00:00:00' and '2021-10-09 23:59:00'
    group by trx_status
) as c
group by trx_status
```

I need a result that looks like this

```
GR001 - 200
GR002 - 3
GR003 - 23
GR0027 - 90
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: How is this related yo `jQuery`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I think he looked for 'query'.

Comment: Yes I am looking for query that Hide the following:   trx_status,
(trx_count)

Comment: sorry about that @CarstenLøvboAndersen It is my first time to upload a question